# Twitter API Request Limit Problem

Tags: twitter, java

I've written a small java program to download all friends' and followers' profile pictures from twitter. But i'm getting an error because only 150 requests per hour per IP address is allowed.

the exact error is:

```
twitter4j.TwitterException: 400:The request was invalid.  An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during rate limiting.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <request>/users/show/92715794.xml</request>
  <error>Rate limit exceeded. Clients may not make more than 150 requests per hour.</error>
</hash>
```

Is there a way around this problem...??? Please help...

Comment: Oh yes, Why don't you use OAuth? BASIC Http authentication has been deprecated as of 1 July 2010. You can get 350 requests per hour. Only thing is you need to create an application on Twitter.com.

Comment: Might just be coincidental but the Twitter user in the error message appears to relate to one of those "fill in a survey" spam sites and Googling their URL plus "spam" leads to lots of identical tweets on compromised or phony Twitter accounts. Spam like this is one of the reasons that Twitter has rate limiting in the first place

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a developer you can request whitelisting of your account, raising the limit to 20 000 requests / hours. Read more at http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Rate-limiting

Comment: Just what I was about to say. +1

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way around this problem...???

Yes.  Slow down your process so that it only makes 150 requests per hour.

Comment: i can not slow down since i need to download the profile pictures. I could have if i was simply building a twitter client of sorts.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. Get your app whitelisted (20 000 req/h)
2. Instead of doing unauthenticated requests, authenticate with OAuth (350 req/h)
3. Slow down you requests

Judging for your description, I don't know if you can expect to get whitelisted. Given that you won't gain to much, implementing OAuth might be not worth the trouble. It seems you are stuck to taking it slow.

Comment: Twitter now has OAuth has authentication, BASIC has been deprecated.