# The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why

Tags: java, jsp

I am developing my first Java Twitter application;

I have already developed few modules like search by username , search by #tagname, search by geolocation .

It was working properly, but today suddendly it's showing some errors.

I am posting few lines of the error code

> 400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why.

This is the status code will be returned during rate limiting (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 400 Bad Request</h1>
    <p>Bad Request</p>
    TwitterException    { exceptionCode=[d35baff5-08c3b248], statusCode=400,
    retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, 
    version=2.2.5}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:185)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java
```

Can anyone helped me out ? What is the reason I am getting this type of error and how can I will solve this error ?

Comment: Please use proper english when posting, all these abbreviations make your text very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer you can request whitelisting of your account, raising the limit to 20 000 requests / hours.

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265070/twitter-api-request-limit-problem)

Comment: Thanks for the ans .Now I understood where is my mistake.As I am totly new to twitter application.So If u dnt mind Can u plz tel me how i will do the raising limit 20000 requests / hr.. Thanks

Comment: You can see the solutions in the link what i provided